# Data Validation Custom Formula with 'OR'

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a custom data validation formula to determine if the data entered into a cell is a valid first line of address.
The only way I can figure this out is to use begins with, but it would need to contain the 'OR' function.

so for example if the data begins with a number, the letter "F" followed by a number or the word "flat" followed by a number the the data entered should match the validation entered for that cell.

But I can not seem to find the right formula for that method.

If you could help me with this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For your examples:

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^\d|^F\d|^flat\d")
```

It is case sensitive. [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

Comment: I have tried that in the custom formula section of data validation, but it does not work